# access the json elements using loop in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, for-loop

can anyone give me a correct solution for this program.how to print all values using foreach loop.I tried but I got an error as undefined values Thanks in advance...I am waiting for reply...

```
differ.json:


{
"table":
[
   {
      "place":
      {
        "STATE":"TAMILNADU",
        "DISTRICT":"VELLORE"
      }
   },
  {
    "place":
    {
      "STATE":"KERALA",
      "DISTRICT":"ALAPHUZHA"
    }
  },
  {
    "place":
    {
      "STATE":"ANDHRA PRAADESH",
      "DISTRICT":"KUNTUR"
    }
  }
]
}
Nodejs file:

var fs = require('fs');
var obj1 = fs.readFileSync('differ.json', 'utf8');
var data=JSON.parse(obj1);
var countobjects = Object.keys(data).length;
console.log(countobjects);
for( var place in data.table)
{
    for( var field in data.table[place])
    {
        console.log("State:" + data.table[place].field);
        console.log("District:" + data.table[place].field);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach`as below :

```
data.table.forEach(function(element){
  console.log(element.place.STATE);
  console.log(element.place.DISTRICT);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `of` instead of `in` for your loop, and it can be simplified using ES6 string template literals like so...

```js
const data = { "table": [{ "place": { "STATE":"TAMILNADU", "DISTRICT":"VELLORE" } }, { "place": { "STATE":"KERALA", "DISTRICT":"ALAPHUZHA" } }, { "place": { "STATE":"ANDHRA PRAADESH", "DISTRICT":"KUNTUR" } }] }

for (const d of data.table) {
  const s = `State: ${d.place.STATE}\nDistrict: ${d.place.DISTRICT}`
  console.log(s)
}
```